# Join between two tables where the 'where' condition contains a MAX value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, MEMBER and ORDER and want to return the Member_ID and Name from MEMBER along with the most recent order date from ORDER for that member.

Example:

MEMBER:

```
Member_ID     Name
001           Fred
002           Joe
003           Dave
```

ORDER:

```
Member_ID   Order_ID    Date
001         0001        01/01/2017
001         0002        15/02/2017
002         0003        10/03/2017
003         0004        12/04/2017
```

I can return the most recent order by the query: `**Select MAX(DATE) From ORDER Where Member_ID = 001 GROUP BY Member_ID**`

But when I join to the Select statement with the remainder, both rows for Member_ID '001' are returned:

```
Select m.Member_ID, m.Name, o.DATE from MEMBER m
INNER JOIN ORDER o
ON m.Member_ID = o.Member_ID
Where o.DATE = (Select MAX(DATE) From ORDER Where Member_ID = 001 GROUP BY Member_ID)
AND m.Member_ID = 001
```

Could anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the path you are on.  You want a *correlated subquery* rather than `group by`:

```
Select m.Member_ID, m.Name, o.DATE
from members m join
     orders o
     on m.member_id = o.member_id
Where o.DATE = (Select max(o2.DATE)
                From orders o2
                Where o2.Member_ID = o.member_id
               ) and
      m.Member_ID = '001';
```

In SQL Server, it would be more natural to express this using window functions:

```
Select m.Member_ID, m.Name, o.DATE
from members m join
     (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by member_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
     on m.member_id = o.member_id
Where m.Member_ID = '001';
```

Or because you only want the maximum date, you can just use aggregation (in any database):

```
Select m.Member_ID, m.Name, max(o.DATE)
from members m join
     orders o
     on m.member_id = o.member_id
Where m.Member_ID = '001'
group by m.Member_ID, m.Name;
```

Notes:

- `order` is a reserved word in SQL Server *and* a SQL keyword.  It is a bad name for a table.  I changed the table names to be plural.
- If `member_id` starts with leading zeros, then it is a string, not a number.  The value should be enclosed in double quotes (or no leading zeros used).
- Your `GROUP BY` subquery returns multiple values, that will result in an error with `=`.
- Your `JOIN` conditions are incorrect, based on the names you are using in the tables.

Comment: Thank-you for the information. Yes, I corrected the join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You missed id condition in subquery

```
select a.member_id, a.name, b.order_id, b.date
from member a left join order b on (a.member_id=b.member_id)
where a.member_id=001
and b.date in (select max(date) from order where member_id=001 group by member_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the most recent date on the records of each member, you can use ROW_NUMBER() and ORDER it BY date in DESCending order and elect only the row number 1.

```
SELECT m.member_id, 
       m.name, 
       o.date
 FROM members m 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT *,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY member_id 
                                          ORDER BY date DESC) as rnum
              FROM orders
           ) o
   ON m.member_id = o.member_id
WHERE o.rnum = 1 --this determines the most recent record of each member
  AND m.member_id = '001';
```